# How to find gradle lintOptions document for android?

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I got "...is not translated in ... [MissingTranslation]"error in my android project.   I searched by google find something works as  `abortOnError false`  and a document about [lintOptions](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Lint-support).

But I do not want to ignore all lint errors, so I copied xml created by Eclipse as `lintConfig file("default-lint.xml")`, and it works.
I want to know where can I find the full document about all lint options that can set in the lint.xml?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks) you can find all the Lint issues you can suppress via the lint.xml like this:
`

```
<!-- Ignore the ObsoleteLayoutParam issue in the given files -->
<issue id="ObsoleteLayoutParam">
    <ignore path="res/layout/activation.xml" />
    <ignore path="res/layout-xlarge/activation.xml" />
</issue>

<!-- Ignore the UselessLeaf issue in the given file -->
<issue id="UselessLeaf">
    <ignore path="res/layout/main.xml" />
</issue>

<!-- Change the severity of hardcoded strings to "error" -->
<issue id="HardcodedText" severity="error" />
```

`

Comment: A better formatted lint.xml file can be found here https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#sample-lint.xml-file

Answer (score 83):

Here are all the available options (original source [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Lint-support))

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet true
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
        // if true, only report errors
        ignoreWarnings true
        // if true, emit full/absolute paths to files with errors (true by default)
        absolutePaths true
        // if true, check all issues, including those that are off by default
        checkAllWarnings true
        // if true, treat all warnings as errors
        warningsAsErrors true
        // turn off checking the given issue id's
        disable 'TypographyFractions','TypographyQuotes'
        // turn on the given issue id's
        enable 'RtlHardcoded','RtlCompat', 'RtlEnabled'
        // check *only* the given issue id's
        check 'NewApi', 'InlinedApi'
        // if true, don't include source code lines in the error output
        noLines true
        // if true, show all locations for an error, do not truncate lists, etc.
        showAll true
        // Fallback lint configuration (default severities, etc.)
        lintConfig file("default-lint.xml")
        // if true, generate a text report of issues (false by default)
        textReport true
        // location to write the output; can be a file or 'stdout'
        textOutput 'stdout'
        // if true, generate an XML report for use by for example Jenkins
        xmlReport false
        // file to write report to (if not specified, defaults to lint-results.xml)
        xmlOutput file("lint-report.xml")
        // if true, generate an HTML report (with issue explanations, sourcecode, etc)
        htmlReport true
        // optional path to report (default will be lint-results.html in the builddir)
        htmlOutput file("lint-report.html")

        // set to true to have all release builds run lint on issues with severity=fatal
        // and abort the build (controlled by abortOnError above) if fatal issues are found
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        // Set the severity of the given issues to fatal (which means they will be
        // checked during release builds (even if the lint target is not included)
        fatal 'NewApi', 'InlineApi'
        // Set the severity of the given issues to error
        error 'Wakelock', 'TextViewEdits'
        // Set the severity of the given issues to warning
        warning 'ResourceAsColor'
        // Set the severity of the given issues to ignore (same as disabling the check)
        ignore 'TypographyQuotes'
    }
}
```

Comment: InlineApi -> InlinedApi

Answer (score 6):

You can find the official documentation in android gradle dsl site:

http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions